# Difference between connection timed out vs Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server

Tags: java, connection

I am faced with two kinds of exceptions:

Exception 1:

`java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out`

Exception 2:

`java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'java.sun.com', port: '80'`

The second one occurs when there is no service hosted on `java.sun.com:80`, but I couldn't figure out the first exception. It seems I am sending syn to host and the host welcomes me but is not sending syn + ack back. Am I right? I am not able to take tcp dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one occurs when the host is reachable but the response takes very long time. because of internet connection or the server is very slow.
The second one occurs when the service is not reachable.